# Utility GIS - Type of data cleanup needed & Effort

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-quality

I am trying to get into Utility GIS and I have been asked by my boss to size up the effort of what it takes to clean up Pipeline, Utility asset GIS data and figure out if there is a way think of a factor like a per linear mile man days of effort.

The data is in the form of ESRI File 
Geodatabase.

Typical clean up related tasks I have are :

1. Data consistency by using domains (Manual Effort) - Per Record Multiplier
2. Topology checks (ArcToolbox) Per Featureclass Multiplier
3. CAD to GIS conversion (Per Feature Class Multiplier)
4. Visual QCs

Can you suggest any other tasks typically for cleaning pipeline data and any assessment of what you would think of a man-day multiplier?

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the [ArcGIS Data Reviewer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/arcgis-data-reviewer) extension. It has lots of great tools that are not in core ArcGIS Desktop. There is also a [Data Reviewer for Water Utilities](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b45477c815e54786ac687e70be757f24).